# Powershell --- code ~/.bashrc does not work (is it a linux thing?)

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code

first image is the powershell `code ~/.bashrc`

[Powershell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VIDOP.png)

second image is the wsl ubunti `code ~/.bashrc`

[wsl ubuntu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iH8OE.png)

my question really goes, does this not work on powershell? is it a linux feature?

thanks, salamat, arigatou

ps: oof need 10 rep for images, this my first question so yeahhh

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551).

Answer (score 0):

.bashrc is a file that contain code that is executed when WSL or Linux Bash shell is invoked. PowerShell has nothing to do with it. In Powershell, you can use Profiles for that. You can place powershell code in Profile and that will work like bashrc. To create a profile use `new-item $profile -type file` and then to open it in Notepad `notepad $profile`. Then you can add powershell code there.